# How and where to install Git for MAC OS X 10.5.8

Tags: macos, git

I found some instructions how to install git, but they all seem to require leopard or something I don't have, or require some skills to do the installation manually. I suck with computers, so I would really look for an answer aimed for the computer illiterate.

My computer is Macbook air with MAC OS X 10.5.8.

Comment: Read this [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-mac) on how to download and install.

Answer (score 1):

You could try MacPorts--install the MacPorts .dmg file, then in Terminal, do:

`sudo port install git`

If you want a GUI front end to GIT, you could check out [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl) and/or GitHub for Mac. (I believe the latter will work with non-GitHub accounts). There's also [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) which is paid software.